# disable div when another div is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have 6 div and I want to disable or Unclick the other five div, if a div is clicked and if the clicked div is click again the other five div will be available again. Sorry I don't have any code yet, I a beginner. I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Add OnClick event and call $.Hide() for every other div except clicked. And it is not code writing service. So if you not provide your implementation we cannot add fixes to it. See that https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please note that Stackoverflow is not a coding service, and we expect you to have done your research and come up with an attempt at solving your own task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can try something like this :

```js
$('div').click(function(){
 $('div').not(this).toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide{
  visibility : hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Exemple 1</div>
<div>Exemple 2</div>
<div>Exemple 3</div>
<div>Exemple 4</div>
<div>Exemple 5</div>
<div>Exemple 6</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the question as answered.